# Do extended suspended chords higher than ninth (9sus*) exist?

Tags: chords, harmony

There are extended suspended chords, essentially suspended chords with added tones higher than the 5th degree of a scale. The only extended sus chords I know are 7sus2 (C-D-G-Bb), 7sus4 (C-F-G-Bb), and 9sus4 (C-F-G-Bb-D). Additionally, it is impossible to have a 9sus2 chord, that would have the notes C-D-G-Bb-D (duplicate notes). But, there are extended sus chords higher that go higher than the 9th degree (11th, 13th...)?

Comment: Please don't change your core question to ask something new. You can always ask a new question and use this as a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a sus13.    These days we accept a dominant 13th chord on its own terms.   Earlier textbooks prefer it to be a neatly resolved suspension.  They might even criticise the second example for being un-prepared.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, sort of -- bear [with me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NrPOZRD-0Q#t=7) on this one. You can suspend what you might analyse as the 13th resolving down to the 12th.

[image: 6-5 suspensions over V resolving to I]

But need we call this a 13-12 suspension or would it be OK to call it a 6-5 suspension? And is it even a suspension at all? [It's been argued](http://forum.emusictheory.com/read.php?5,2947,2959) that this "suspension figure" is not a suspension because the would-be suspension note is not a dissonance in the chord.

Comment: Would you consider it legitimate to call it a suspension, if the listener clearly expects the voice to move? You go 6-5, 6-5, 6-5 a dozen times but then you leave it at 6...  :)

Comment: Isn't that the whole definition of a suspension - a note outside the chord that is expected to resolve?

Comment: @LaurencePayne - But aren't anticipations also notes outside the chord that are expected to resolve (this time by the chord changing to accommodate that note)?

Comment: Yeah, they're all the same sort of thing!  But I don't think we can define the label  by whether the listener EXPECTS the resolution.  It's the same thing whether it happens once or 20 times in a row.

Comment: Labels for relatively general concepts -- the sort of thing that these are all examples of -- can be useful. Here, perhaps "non-harmony note" (or "accented non-harmony note") would be appropriate. But labels for more specific concepts are also useful, so that we can be precise and distinguish among suspensions, anticipations, appoggiaturas, and (accented) passing notes. By all means point out commonality between examples of the same sort of thing, but let's keep our subcategories, too.

Comment: I must be dense! Where is the 13th/6th? I see seventh chords, a ninth chord, and simple triads. If the 5 of resolution is above the `G`, the preceding `E` are a seventh and a ninth.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis How would you classify the E as part of the chord with G as the bass, before the E resolves to D?

Comment: @RosieF, ...ugh! yes, as sixths. The `E`'s are dotted, the fog has lifted!